# NativeScript: how to style a listview itemTemplate

Tags: android, css, class, listview, nativescript

I have the following NativeScript code:

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *">
        <ListView items="{{ items }}" row="1">
            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                <Image url="{{ url }}" />
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

I would like to style the ListView-Item, giving it a padding so each image has a little bit of whitespace around it. I tried giving it a class and style the class in the css but I wasn't able to change it.

I was however able to style the image itself (giving it a margin). Is it possible to style the listviewItem-container (like I would style a div-container in css)?

Answer (score 5):

You are right! It is not possible right now to style the item container - only the item content. We will think how to enable this in the future.

Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Border element to wrap your itemTemplate contents.

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *">
        <ListView items="{{ items }}" row="1">
            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                <Border borderWidth="0">
                    <Image url="{{ url }}" />
                </Border>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: For know it's the only solution for 1.0

Answer (score 2):

For now (1.5.2), you can put your images inside the layout container and apply styling to that container:

```
<Page loaded="onPageLoaded">
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *">
        <ListView items="{{ items }}" row="1">
            <ListView.itemTemplate >
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image url="{{ url }}" horizontalAlignment="stretch"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.itemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```